# How to design a task recurrently every 10 minutes in Android?

Tags: android

I hope to do a restore operation recurrently every 10 minutes, and I hope that the function will be keep live even if I restart my mobile phone.

The following content if my planning, I don't know whether it's right, or do you have more better way?

Step 1: Invoke `EnableCleanupService(Context mContext)` in a Activity,  the system will do a restore operation recurrently every 10 minutes, the system will keep to do a restore operation recurrently every 10 minutes even if I close the APP, right?

Step 2: In order to do the restore operation recurrently every 10 minutes after I restart my mobile phone, the system  invoke  `EnableCleanupService(context)` on `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` automatically even if I don't open the App. Right?

**Step 1**

```
public static void EnableCleanupService(Context mContext){
        AlarmManager alarmManager;
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();       
        now= now+mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FirstTigger)*60*1000;
        int nextTime=mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.ScheduleTimeMin)*60*10*1000;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                now,
                nextTime,
                GetPendingIntent(mContext)
        );
    }


private static PendingIntent GetPendingIntent(Context mContext){
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=null;

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext,
                0,
                new Intent(mContext, CleanupService.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        return pendingIntent;
}


public class CleanupService  extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {              
        //Do Task
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

```
<receiver android:name="bll.CleanupBootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>


public class CleanupBootReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            EnableCleanupService(context)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems it will work as you expected but try to use JobScheduler concept instead of AlarmManager. Please check android developer doc.

Comment: What's your question, exactly? Are you asking if this is an appropriate solution? Or are you asking why it's not working?

Comment: To Srinivasan : Thanks! could you show me some sample code or document about JobScheduler ?

Comment: To  Mike M: Thanks! my question is: 1. Whether is my thinking about how to do a repeated task right? 2. is there other better way to do a repeated task ?

Comment: Yeah, `AlarmManager` is certainly a viable option for this type of requirement, and it looks like you've got it set up correctly, if you remembered the `<service>` element, too. As Srinivasan mentioned, though, `JobScheduler` might also be an option for you, but it's only available since API level 21, and I think the minimum repeat interval for that is 15 minutes.

Comment: I should've mentioned, though, that doing something like this every 10 minutes is often not user- or battery-friendly. You might reconsider this, unless it's an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done seems to be correct.In my opinion AlarmManager is the best if you want to perform any time-based or time-bound operation. If you have any doubts regarding AlarmManager. You can read this [Working with AlarmManager | With Example](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/android-example-alarm-manager-complete-working/)

One important thing though. Setting a repetitive Alarm every 10 minutes is a very bad experience, it drains the battery and also some custom cleaner applications might cancel your Alarm as "spam".